# Create months between two dates Snowflake SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I just want to generate the months between data range using SQL Query.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gLV7.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a table generator:

```
select '2022-07-04'::date + 
row_number() over(partition by 1 order by null) - 1 GENERATED_DATE
from table(generator(rowcount => 365))
;
```

Just change the start date and the number of days into the series. You can use the `datediff` function to calculate the number of days between the start end end dates.

Edit: I just realized the generator table function requires a constant for the number of rows. That's easily solvable. Just set a higher number of rows than you'll need and specify the end of the series in a qualify clause:

```
set startdate = (select '2022-04-15'::date);
set enddate = (select '2022-07-04'::date);

select $startdate::date + 
row_number() over(partition by 1 order by null) - 1 GENERATED_DATE
from table(generator(rowcount => 100000))
qualify GENERATED_DATE <= $enddate
;
```

Comment: What is the goal of `PARTITION BY 1` when the query is executed in context of single partition and this clause is optional? Does it improve performance?

Comment: That's a great question, Lukasz. In this case it doesn't matter. I habitually specify one (or deal with the effects of omitting it) because of how Snowflake runs procedural UDTFs. If there's no `partition by` clause, Snowflake will split the rows into blocks and run them in parallel through the UDTF. The code in the callback functions may or may not be okay with that: `When no partitioning is used, the Snowflake execution engine partitions the input itself according to multiple factors, such as the size of the warehouse processing the function and the cardinality of the input relation.`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a table generator in the CTE, and then select from the CTE and cartesian join to your table with data and use a case statement to see if the date in the generator is between your start and to dates.

Then select from it:

```
select user_id, x_date
from (
  with dates as (
  select '2019-01-01'::date + row_number() over(order by 0) x_date
  from table(generator(rowcount => 1500))
  )
  select d.x_date, t.*,
  case 
    when d.x_date between t.from_date and t.to_date then 'Y' else 'N' end target_date
  from dates d, my_table t --deliberate cartesian join
  )
where target_date = 'Y'
order by 1,2
```

Output:

```
USER_ID X_DATE
1       2/20/2019
1       2/21/2019
1       2/22/2019
1       2/23/2019
2       2/22/2019
2       2/23/2019
2       2/24/2019
2       2/25/2019
2       2/26/2019
2       2/27/2019
2       2/28/2019
3       3/1/2019
3       3/2/2019
3       3/3/2019
3       3/4/2019
3       3/5/2019
```

**=======EDIT========**

Based on your comments below, you are actually looking for something different than your original screenshots. Ok, so here we are still using the table generator, and then we're truncating the month to the first day of the month where the x-date is YES.

```
    select distinct t.user_id, t.from_date, t.to_date, date_trunc('MONTH', z.x_date) as trunc_month
    from (
        with dates as (
        select '2019-01-01'::date + row_number() over(order by 0) x_date
        from table(generator(rowcount => 1500))
        )
        select d.x_date, t.*,
        case 
         when d.x_date between t.from_date and t.to_date then 'Y' else 'N' end target_date
        from dates d, my_table t
          )z
    join my_table t
      on z.user_id = t.user_id
    where z.target_date = 'Y'
    order by 1,2
```

Output (modified User ID 3 to span 2 months):

```
USER_ID FROM_DATE   TO_DATE     TRUNC_MONTH
1       2/20/2019   2/23/2019   2/1/2019
2       2/22/2019   2/28/2019   2/1/2019
3       2/25/2019   3/5/2019    2/1/2019
3       2/25/2019   3/5/2019    3/1/2019
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ,  could i know how get month for range of year  . EX : 2012-01-01 to 2012-12-30 , from this range I  need month wise

Comment: @AadhilImam Not sure what you mean. In your second screenshot, you have it broken out by Day, not Month. Can you update your question with the desired output?

Comment: Now i update the question with example screenshot , could you check please ?

Comment: can you help me to solve this ?

Comment: @AadhilImam Just Updated. Having this info upfront in the question would have been better so that we know what you are trying to produce.