# Find missing snapshots and fill the records for them

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I have the following snapshot table with lots of Activation IDs. Whenever a record Expires based on the Valid Until column the snapshot for the month just drops off and then continues ones the subscription is reactivated. In the example below 6/1/2022 is missing and I need to find a way to manually fill the value for it.

| Activation_ID | Snapshot_Date | Row_Generation | Status | Valid_Until |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2022-08-01 | Main source | Active | 2022-12-18 |
| 1234 | 2022-07-01 | Main source | Reactivated | 2022-12-18 |
| 1234 | 2022-05-01 | Main source | Active | 2022-05-15 |

The output should be something like this. For the ones missing we create a new record.

| Activation_ID | Snapshot_Date | Row_Generation | Status | Valid_Until |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2022-08-01 | Main source | Active | 2022-12-18 |
| 1234 | 2022-07-01 | Main source | Reactivated | 2022-12-18 |
| 1234 | 2022-06-01 | Manual generation | Expired | 2022-05-15 |
| 1234 | 2022-05-01 | Main source | Active | 2022-05-15 |

**UPDATE:**
This is my code. The problem is that it works only for the current selection. It filters for the month that I have specified in `dateadd('month', 0, date_trunc('month', current_date))`. I can't rewrite it in a way to be efficient and run over all snapshots rather than the one that I specify.

```
with last_snapshot as (
    select
        ls.*
    from {{ ref('BRDG_FLEXERA_ANALYSIS_MONTHLY_BASE') }} ls
    --Applies the filter to get only the current month to load
    where ls.SNAPSHOT_DATE = dateadd('month', 0, date_trunc('month', current_date))
), 
--Joins and adds in the previous periods columns which are needed for PIT compare
current_snapshot as (
    select 
        --Columns to be added from the previous snapshot
        ps.FLEXERA_ACTIVATION_ID "PREVIOUS_FLEXERA_ACTIVATION_ID_CTE",
        ps.SNAPSHOT_DATE "PREVIOUS_SNAPSHOT_DATE_CTE",
        ps.CURRENT_LICENCE_STATUS "PREVIOUS_LICENCE_STATUS_CTE",
        ps.REPORTING_STATUS "PREVIOUS_REPORTING_STATUS_CTE",
        ps.COUNT "COUNT_CTE",
        ls.*
    from last_snapshot ls

    left join {{ ref('BRDG_FLEXERA_ANALYSIS_MONTHLY_BASE') }} ps
        on ps.FLEXERA_ACTIVATION_ID = ls.FLEXERA_ACTIVATION_ID
        and ps.SNAPSHOT_DATE = ls.PREVIOUS_SNAPSHOT_DATE
),
--This helps us to determine if a record dropped off from the last snapshot to the latest one.
--For ones missing we create a new Churn record
previous_snapshots as (
     select
        --Builds the columns to identify the previous snapshot
        dateadd('month', 0, date_trunc('month', current_date)) "CURRENT_MONTH_DATE_NEW",
        add_months(CURRENT_MONTH_DATE_NEW, -1) "PREVIOUS_MONTH_DATE",
        ps.*
    from {{ ref('BRDG_FLEXERA_ANALYSIS_MONTHLY_BASE') }} ps
    
    --Joins the current data to the previous snapshot to flag what exists in the current which was in the previous
    left join current_snapshot cs
        on ps.FLEXERA_ACTIVATION_ID = cs.FLEXERA_ACTIVATION_ID

    where ps.SNAPSHOT_DATE = PREVIOUS_MONTH_DATE     --Filters to get the previous snapshot
        and ps.CURRENT_LICENCE_STATUS != 'Expired'   --Filters to get the previous snapshot
        and cs.FLEXERA_ACTIVATION_ID is NULL         --Filters to get only those rows which were in the last snapshot but not the current
)
```

Comment: This answer may help (at least with the generating calendar part) and inspire you to code the rest. Populating the "valid_until" column with the prior expired date will need some thought, especially if there are multiple gaps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73322297/create-months-between-two-dates-snowflake-sql/73323079#73323079

Answer (score 0):

I think we may need to better understand if multiple gaps can exist and what the logic should be for setting the valid_until column, but maybe this will suffice. Will just need to convert this to an update/insert statement.

```
with trunc_dates as ( --this is a calendar generator
  select distinct date_trunc('MONTH', z.x_date) as date_month
  from (
    select '2019-01-01'::date + row_number() over(order by 0) x_date
    from table(generator(rowcount => 1500)))z
), 
min_max_dates as ( --determine min and max dates per subscription
  select activation_id, date_trunc('MONTH', min(valid_until)) as min_date, date_trunc('MONTH', max(valid_until)) as max_date
  from my_table
  group by activation_id
),
contract_dates as ( --creating rows for every month between min and max date
select mmd.activation_id, td.date_month
 from trunc_dates td, min_max_dates mmd --deliberate cartesian join
 where td.date_month >= mmd.min_date 
   and td.date_month <= mmd.max_date
   and td.date_month < current_date
)
select distinct cd.activation_id, 
  cd.date_month as snapshot_date, 
  coalesce(t.row_generation, 'manual generation') as row_generation, 
  coalesce(t.status, 'expired') as status, 
  t.valid_until 
from contract_dates cd
left join my_table t
  on cd.activation_id = t.activation_id
 and cd.date_month = date_trunc('MONTH', t.snapshot_date)
order by 1,2 desc
```

Output:

| ACTIVATION_ID | SNAPSHOT_DATE | ROW_GENERATION | STATUS | VALID_UNTIL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 8/1/2022 | main | active | 12/18/2022 |
| 1234 | 7/1/2022 | main | reactivated | 12/18/2022 |
| 1234 | 6/1/2022 | manual generation | expired |  |
| 1234 | 5/1/2022 | main | reactivated | 05/15/2022 |

As mentioned before, this will need to be adjusted if you really need to populate a "valid until" date on those expired rows.

Comment: Thank you for the effort in answering. The code that you have provided works to some extent but it generated a manual generation row since the current date (and td.date_month < current_date). I need to generate only one manual record. The thing is that sometimes when the subscription starts it has a valid_until date = '2026-06' and then on a later snapshot it is overwritten with the actual subscription end date for ex '2021-05'.  Meaning that it should end on 2021-05 instead of 2026 or as in your code the current date 2022-08. I have updated my question with code and the challenge.